# How to check if MySQL tables exist without asking MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have to check for the existence of several tables from a shell script, without accessing the MySQL daemon. Is the presence of `.frm` files reliable to determine if the tables exist or not? Here's what I have been doing, but it doesn't seem to work all the time (there may be an error in another part of the system):

```
for table in $TABLES; do
    if [ -f /data/mysql/${database}/${table}.frm ]; then
        ...
        ...
    fi
done
```

Is this reliable? If not, is there another way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there will [always](http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/MySQL_Internals_File_Formats) be a `.frm` file for each table.

Comment: The question is, will there always be a table for each `.frm` file?

Comment: @Thomas:  The answer to that is yes, unless you have corrupted tables or just copied the .frm files around for whatever reason.  .frm files are the only constant between MySQL's various database engines.